# How to enable cron backup in docker gitlab-ce

Tags: docker, backup, cron

I am using [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/) Docker image to install `gitlab-ce`

To configure it, you can override a file called `gitlab.rb` by mounting it as  a volume at `./gitlab.rb:/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb:ro`

You can find gitlab.rb [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/files/gitlab-config-template/gitlab.rb.template)

At the backup section I currently have this :

```
## For setting up backups
## see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/629def0a7a26e7c2326566f0758d4a27857b52a3/README.md#backups

# gitlab_rails['manage_backup_path'] = true
# gitlab_rails['backup_path'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/backups"
gitlab_rails['backup_archive_permissions'] = 0644 # See: http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/backup_restore.html#backup-archive-permissions
# gitlab_rails['backup_pg_schema'] = 'public'
gitlab_rails['backup_keep_time'] = 604800
# gitlab_rails['backup_upload_connection'] = {
#   'provider' => 'AWS',
#   'region' => 'eu-west-1',
#   'aws_access_key_id' => 'AKIAKIAKI',
#   'aws_secret_access_key' => 'secret123'
# }
# gitlab_rails['backup_upload_remote_directory'] = 'my.s3.bucket'
# gitlab_rails['backup_multipart_chunk_size'] = 104857600
# gitlab_rails['backup_encryption'] = 'AES256' # Turns on AWS Server-Side Encryption with Amazon S3-Managed Keys for backups
```

If you see as recommended in the code this [link](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/629def0a7a26e7c2326566f0758d4a27857b52a3/README.md#backups), it says :

```
# Scheduling a backup

To schedule a cron job that backs up your repositories and GitLab metadata, use the root user:
    sudo su -
    crontab -e
There, add the following line to schedule the backup for everyday at 2 AM:
    0 2 * * * /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create
```

## Questions

- Is there a way to do this at the installation instead of doing it manually ?
- Is the cron task already running ? Should we not start it by doing `crontab -f` ?
- What file does the command `crontab -e` modify ?
- To change the manual configuration part of the tutorial, with a cron file like `/etc/cron.d/my-backup-cron` will it be the same expected behavior ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, BigDong... Using Docker means you're not going to have an init system available to run crons in the container. That's because whatever command is specified in the `CMD` Dockerfile directive (or `ENTRYPOINT`) is going to be run as PID1 inside your container. This is why you can't `service myservice start` or similar.

The "best practice" here would be to just run your backup utility inside a new gitlab-ce container. What this means is that you'll use `docker run` to create a "backup" gitlab-ce image that you run on some occasion triggered by a cron on the host machine. Then your backup command will actually be in your `docker run` command. That sounds confusing, so let me illustrate. Something like this:

`docker run -d --rm gitlab-ce sh -c "/opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create"`

If you're using data volumes in the container to persist data (or store on a specific directory on the host machine via bind-mount), you should change this to:

`docker run -d --rm --volumes-from gitlab-ce gitlab-ce sh -c "/opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create"`

The "backup" gitlab-ce image uses `--volumes-from gitlab-ce` (or whatever your gitlab-ce container is called) in order to access the data volumes in the container, if any. **But** since you are specifically using S3 for backup storage, as defined in your config, you don't need to worry about handling the volumes. I'm just including this for clarification since using volumes is a far more common situation than not.

You can probably follow from this what is happening, but for those readers that cannot, you're running the `gitlab-ce` *image* in order to start a new *container* which is only running the single command to perform your backup. Actually, it's running `sh -c` with your `gitlab-rake` backup utility and its parameter as the argument. Then, you will use `crontab -e` on the *host* to run this command every day at two in the morning in whatever timezone the host is set to:

`0 2 * * * docker run -d --rm gitlab-ce sh -c "...gitlab-rake..."`

Kind of important is the `--rm` option. That tells Docker to delete any intermediary containers that are created, so that you don't have a ton of orphaned backup containers laying around in your `docker ps -a`.

Another option to consider here is to mount the data of your gitlab-ce container into a bind-mounted volume on the host machine, and then you can operate on the data from the host. However, I suppose here I would *highly* recommend that you use whatever backup infrastructure is provided by the application. In this case, the `gitlab-rake` utility.

Another option, if this is not attractive for whatever reason, would be to create a cron container that uses `docker run` or `docker exec` to run your tasks in other containers.

With respect to your specific need to back up Gitlab... Another option to consider is [this Gitlab docker image](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab). It has built in the ability to run backups at some specific point in time, and is what I use personally for automatically backing up. It looks like new versions allow you to backup directly to S3, instead of running a cron on the host to move to S3. In this case, where a docker image specifically offers the ability to backup without using external resources, it's fine to do it this way. Broadly speaking, separation of concerns (and backup being a separate concern), you should not combine these functions into a single container. People's instinct is to put as much as possible into a container, but you'll find that Docker works best as a microservices provider.

The main thing is that Docker offers you a lot of choice with respect to getting things done. Part of its power is that there are usually several ways to accomplish a single task, and so it's up to you to determine what works best for your situation. Good luck!

**tl;dr** Use `docker run` to fire up the provided gitlab-ce backup utility (gitlab-rake) triggered by a cronjob running on your host machine.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. I want to implement backup inside the container because I will have hundred of containers running and it's better if each backup is handled by the image itself. I did install supervisor to run two process, `gitlab-ce` and `cron -f`, gitlab started but still no backup in my folder.

Comment: I've adjusted my answer to include using a specific and widely-used Gitlab Docker image that has automatic backup (and offsite-to-S3), without using the typical external cron/backup option.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what container will be installed on each host. I want the cron (host or container) to start only when the container is running. The container name is generated mesos side. Do you have any idea in mind to apply your recommendation for such a case ?

Comment: I don't use Mesos, but I can't imagine it doesn't provide event triggers for starting a container. If you absolutely can't use a cron on the host, is there some reason you can't use the sameersbn/docker-gitlab image I mention? At least you should be able to play with it until you figure out how that image runs its backup rake task from within the same container. I have always used this image for self-hosted Gitlab, and since your answer have started using the auto-backup-to-S3 function it provides. I really suggest taking a look at it.

Comment: I don't use auto-backup-to-S3, it's just the part edited from the template file I have added here. The auto-backup-to-S3 might also use a cron I guess.
I used to work with the  sameersbn/docker-gitlab and the gitlab-ce image fit's better for my need because it has a better portability compare to sameersbn one.

Comment: I think you're looking for a very specific answer to your question and I'm offering broad advice for solving the problem and places to look for assistance.

Comment: Are you using :latest tagged image ? How does sameersbn image react when GitLab release a new version ? Automatique backup script triggered ?

Comment: I am using the latest tag, yes. Sameersbn has been very, very good about updating his images when new versions of the software are released. I have used sameersbn/gitlab for almost two years now, and he has always been very good about it. And I am triggering automatic backup in the sameersbn/gitlab container using the "GITLAB_BACKUP" (and related) environment variables.

Comment: I wasn't asking about if he keep his image update to date. I was asking how the gitlab update was handled itself. Like if you are running sameersbn/gitlab:latest and running gitlab 8.0.1. When 8.0.2 is release, you can pull the latest semeersbn/gitlab:latest and reinstall gitlab using the previous volumes for 8.0.1. Does the install script take care of running update script to update the database and other stuffs ?

Comment: Read the documentation. Also, I have said explicitly right here that it uses the built-in rake task to run the backup task on a schedule. And no, nothing automatically updates the image. That's not how Docker works.

Comment: I'll accept your response because you look tired and it can help to make you more happy.

Comment: Well, that's not what I'm after. The best way to understand the way this works is to try it out. The sameersbn/gitlab image is light years ahead of the "official" Gitlab image, and offers the ability to back up your data regularly (like a cron) using the rake task inside the container itself. There is no Docker image out there that automatically updates the software (or the data used by the software). This would go against all best practices. (continued)

Comment: There might be some Docker images out there that offer the ability to update the application and data, but the standard way of doing this is to build a new image and mount your data volumes with it. In the case of sameersbn/gitlab, where updating could mean that your new Gitlab can't use your old Postgresql database, then you'll have to find a way to update that data yourself. For example I had to manually export my repositories when I updated my Gitlab from 7.8 to 8.2, and then manually import them in the newest version. But if you're exporting nightly or weekly via backup, no problem.

Comment: What would be awesome is for the official gitlab docker image to have a pre-seeded "project" called "Backup" with .gitlab-ci.yaml that triggers a CI build periodically to backup the installation. This would require a shell runner to be configured. But it will make the image functional from get go.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of the "docker run" approach you can also, according to [Gitlab Doku](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/backups.html), simply issue:

```
docker exec -t <your container name> gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create
```

Comment: link to official documentation:
https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/backups.html#creating-backups-for-gitlab-instances-in-docker-containers

Answer (score 3):

I implemented automatic backups using the following **workaround** via `go-crond` which ships with the omnibus image:

I'm setting these two env vars:

```
BACKUP_CRONTAB = <<-EOF
  SHELL=/bin/bash
  0 2 * * * root gitlab-backup create # Daily at 2am (UTC)
  EOF
GITLAB_POST_RECONFIGURE_SCRIPT = <<-EOF
  echo "$BACKUP_CRONTAB" > "/backup-crontab"
  go-crond "/backup-crontab" &
  EOF
```

The script in `GITLAB_POST_RECONFIGURE_SCRIPT` is automatically executed on startup and starts the backup scheduling.

This is of course just a workaround. [This GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/3492) tracks the implementation of a proper solution.